# Construct a condition in Azure DevOps using 'each'

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

In Azure DevOps (YAML pipeline), we have a stages that should be run only after another set of stages have been skipped.

In the example below, the parameter `copyStages_UAT` can be amended by users when triggering a manual run, meaning it's impossible to hard-code the `dependsOn` and `condition` properties, so necessitating the use of the directive `each`.

```
- template: ../Stages/stage--code--depoly-to-environment.yml
  parameters:
    name: Deploy_PRD_UKS
    displayName: Deploy PRD - UK South
    dependsOn:
    - ${{ each uatStage in parameters.copyStages_UAT }}:
      - Roll_Back_${{ uatStage.name }}
    variables:
    - template: ../Variables/variables--code--global.yml
    - template: ../Variables/variables--code--prd.yml
    environment: PRD
```

This stage above works in a pipeline, however because a successful run results in stages defined in `dependsOn` being skipped, sadly then Azure DevOps will also skip this stage.

To counter this, I'm trying to add a `condition` to check whether or not the previous stages were all skipped.

```
condition: >-
  and(replace(
    ${{ each uatStage in parameters.copyStages_UAT }}:
      eq(dependencies.Roll_Back_${{ uatStage.name }}.result, 'Skipped'), 
  ), ', )', ' )')
```

Unfortunately though, it seems as though I cannot use the directive `each` in this context -

> The directive 'each' is not allowed in this context. Directives are not supported for expressions that are embedded within a string. Directives are only supported when the entire value is an expression.

As `condition` can only be a string, how can I leverage expressions and/or directives to construct my desired condition?

#### Example of desired YAML

Assuming the following value was given for the parameter `copyStages_UAT` -

```
- name: UAT_UKS
  displayName: UAT - UK South
- name: UAT_UKW
  displayName: UAT - UK West
```

This is how the YAML should be compiled. I'm not worried out the format of the condition, as long as the relevant checks are included.

```
- template: ../Stages/stage--code--depoly-to-environment.yml
  parameters:
    name: Deploy_PRD_UKS
    displayName: Deploy PRD - UK South
    dependsOn:
    - Roll_Back_UAT_UKS
    - Roll_Back_UAT_UKW
    condition: >-
      and(
        eq(dependencies.Roll_Back_UAT_UKS.result, 'Skipped'),
        eq(dependencies.Roll_Back_UAT_UKW.result, 'Skipped')
      )
    variables:
    - template: ../Variables/variables--code--global.yml
    - template: ../Variables/variables--code--prd.yml
    environment: PRD
```

Answer (score 1):

Azure DevOps Pipelines does not have a particularly good way for solving this. However, `and(...)`,
[`join(delimiter, ...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#join) and ['Filtered Arrays'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#filtered-arrays) can be used to hackily accomplish this.

---

Observe that the following condition could be rearranged:

```
and(
  eq(dependencies.Roll_Back_UAT_UKW.result, 'Skipped'),
  eq(dependencies.Roll_Back_UAT_UKX.result, 'Skipped'),
  eq(dependencies.Roll_Back_UAT_UKY.result, 'Skipped'),
  eq(dependencies.Roll_Back_UAT_UKZ.result, 'Skipped')
)
```

```
and(
  eq(dependencies.Roll_Back_
  UAT_UKW
  .result, 'Skipped'), eq(dependencies.Roll_Back_
  UAT_UKX
  .result, 'Skipped'), eq(dependencies.Roll_Back_
  UAT_UKY
  .result, 'Skipped'), eq(dependencies.Roll_Back_
  UAT_UKZ
  .result, 'Skipped')
)
```

Or more abstractly, where `PREFIX=eq(dependencies.Roll_Back_` and `SUFFIX=.result, 'Skipped')`:

```
and(
  <PREFIX>
  UAT_UKW
  <SUFFIX>, <PREFIX>
  UAT_UKX
  <SUFFIX>, <PREFIX>
  UAT_UKY
  <SUFFIX>, <PREFIX>
  UAT_UKZ
  <SUFFIX>
)
```

With filtered arrays (`NAMES=parameters.parameterName.*.name`) to extract the name, an aggregation could then be written:

```
and(<PREFIX>${{ join('<PREFIX>, <SUFFIX>', <NAMES>) }}<SUFFIX>)
```

---

Thus:

```yaml
condition: |
  and(
    ne(dependencies.Roll_Back_${{ join('.result, ''Skipped''), ne(dependencies.Roll_Back_', parameters.copyStages_UAT.*.name) }}.result, 'Skipped')
  )
```

But there are some obvious caveats with this:

- If there is 0 elements in `parameters.copyStages_UAT`, then the expression would evaluate to `and(dependencies.Roll_Back_.result, 'Skipped')` which could be non-sensical.
- `and(...)` requires a minimum of 2 arguments, so this could potentially fail if there is only 0 or 1 expression(s). To circumvent this, `True` can be supplied as the first and second argument such that the expression is always valid. If your logic instead requires `or(...)`, then use `False` instead of `True` to keep the meaning consistent.

Therefore, you may need to protect against these scenarios occurring with a modified check:

```yaml
${{ if eq(length(parameters.copyStages_UAT), 0) }}:
  condition: false
${{ else }}:
  condition: |
    and(
      True,
      ne(dependencies.Roll_Back_${{ join('.result, ''Skipped''), ne(dependencies.Roll_Back_', parameters.copyStages_UAT.*.name) }}.result, 'Skipped')
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:**

To summary your demand, you are looking for a expression that you can use it in **condition** while the **dependsOn** value are dynamic. And this stage should run only after another set of dependent stages are all skipped.

As far as I know and tested, this can not be achieved via **each**.

*For further confirmation, I discussed this scenario with our pipeline PM who is more familiar with **each** and YAML pipeline.*

Same as me, he also think this isn't possible to achieve. Because `${{ each }}` expects to be the **outermost** part of a mapping key or value, so you can’t nest it into a condition string.

---

**Work around:**

You could fake it by having a hard-coded stage which depends on the dynamic list, figures out if they were all skipped, and sets an output variable. Then the real final job would only depend on that “decider” job, and its condition would depend on the contents of the output variable.

Figuring out that all upstream dependencies were skipped is something of an exercise for you. You might be able to dynamically construct one step per stage. Those steps map the stage’s status to a variable with a known name scheme. Then the final (hardcoded) step iterates the environment variables of the known name scheme and decides whether the next stage should proceed.

*And... yes, I am aware how ugly that sounds* ☹

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In this case, I only want to run one stage if the stages it depends upon have been skipped. So using your examples above, both images are correct. However, I cannot use `always()` because that would mean that the `DeployEurope` stage would always be run, even if `avaiableazure` and `merlinazure` had been run, and as mentioned it should only be run if those stages it depends on are skipped. I have updated my question to (hopefully) make it clearer.

Comment: @DavidGard, appreciate for this detailed explanation. Got that. That is clear for me now. Would share you suggestions once I have update here.

Comment: @DavidGard, As far as I know, this is not possible to use each directly in condition. To avoid misleading you, I discussed this with our program manager who are most familiar with the function of **each** for further confirmation. Same result, we are all think as of now, you need achieve that by using work around. See my update answer.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. That is not ideal, and I'm not sure that the workaround is going to be feasible. As far as I am aware, you can only share output variables either between tasks in a job, or between jobs in a stage (using `isOutput=true`) - indeed the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts) specifically says "Multi-job output variables only work for jobs in the same stage."

Comment: @DavidGard Ah, we have released a new feature in sprint 168, so that users can access output variable across stages. See this feature timeline doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2020/sprint-168-update#jobs-can-access-output-variables-from-previous-stages

Comment: Ah, OK. I'm still not convinced it's the right thing to do here so I'm exploring other options. But this will absolutely help with another issue I have - I was on the verge of implementing a solution to output to a file and publish an artefact from one stage for consumption by the next, but hoepfully that will no longer be necessary.